# How to Override Yii2 $app->user->identity

Tags: php, yii2

I have a module which uses a secondary database. In it, I am trying to log in to the `user` table from that secondary database. The problem is that the `\Yii::$app->user->identity->id` is using the first database. How should I override the class to do it like this? What I got in my `LoginForm.php` in the module is :

```
public function login()
    {

        if ($this->validate() && $this->user) {
            $isLogged = Yii::$app->getUser()->login($this->user, $this->rememberMe ? $this->module->rememberFor : 0);
            //var_dump($this->user);exit;
            if ($isLogged) {
                $user = \frontend\modules\store\models\User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
                $user->last_login_at = time();
                $user->update();
              //  $this->user->updateAttributes(['last_login_at' => time()]);
            }

            return $isLogged;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

As you can see the `user` class here is overridden and it is using the secondary database. But how should I override the `Yii::$app->user->identity->id` to use this database also? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is secondary database linked with primary database's users any way?

Comment: No. It is not. The site has corporative part ( the main app ) and store ( a module in the forntend ). E.g. `www.domain.com` - corp. and `www.domain.com/store` - store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `Yii2` advanced template, you should consider adding a new sub application. `Yii2` advanced template allows you to have different sessions for `frontend` and `backend` sub applications. [Advanced Template on Same Domain and different sessions](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-shared-hosting.md)

Similarly, you can add a new app, in your case it may be called `store`. If you do it as a separate app, you can simply override identity class and even have different model for `user`. [Help about adding new app is here.](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-adding-more-apps.md)

Answer (score 1):

You can override user identity in config

```
'user' => [
'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', // User must implement the IdentityInterface
'enableAutoLogin' => true,
// 'loginUrl' => ['user/login'],
// ...
```

]

more info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)

Comment: this does not provide the answer to the question what OP wants, did you read the question. do you think the OP would be running 2 different domains till now without this config